# What is the right jquery selector to get all instances of a div based on content inside that div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<div class="list">
 <div class="sortable">
        <div class="contentItem"> Some content </div>
        <div class="contentItem"> Some content </div>
        <div class="contentItem"> Some content </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="list">
 <div class="sortable">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="list">
 <div class="sortable">
        <div class="contentItem"> Some content </div>
        <div class="contentItem"> Some content </div>
        <div class="contentItem"> Some content </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="list">
 <div class="sortable">
 </div>
 </div>
```

and i am trying to hide all of the "list" classes that don't have any "contentItem" divs inside of them.  So its basically taking this

```
 $(".list").hide();
```

which would hide all but ignore the ones that have "contentItem" elements in them

is this possible as a jquery selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and  [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$(".list:not(:has('.contentItem'))").hide();
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/PP4Bh/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`:not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) along with [**`:has()`**](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo selector to accomplish your task.

Try,

```
 $(".list:not(:has('.contentItem'))").hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Eq7h3/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [has() selectors](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to do that

```
$('.list').not(':has(.contentItem)').hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Eq7h3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selectors to select `.list` elements which don't have `.contentItem` in it :

```
$(".list").not(":has(.contentItem)")
$(".list:not(:has('.contentItem'))")
```

To hide just add `.hide()` to it :

```
$(".list").not(":has(.contentItem)").hide();
$(".list:not(:has('.contentItem'))").hide();
```

Comment: Arun has posted the exact answer before 7 minutes.